# Cycles viewport render different than f12 render?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, 3d-view, rendering

What could cause this?
<kbd>f12</kbd>:

[image: F12 Render]

Viewport:

[image: Viewport]

(the <kbd>f12</kbd> has fewer samples, but even when the viewport is at lower samples it looks different..)

I know about color management, but that is at the defaults..

[image: Colo Management]

EDIT: oops.. I know 'log' is not a default, but that is because I was fiddling with it. The image above is rendered with 'default'

The material is quite simple, only a translucent shader. (for testing) I even tried appending everything into a new file to reset all the settings, but no difference.

EDIT2: Uploaded blend 
http://www.pasteall.org/blend/22200

Comment: if you wish to share the blend, or a sufficiently small portion of it so that the effect is still visible, I'd like to have a look.

Comment: You should post your render settings, preferably Sampling, Light Paths, Performance and maybe even Film.

Comment: I currently don't have access to the blend, but when i get it I'll upload it. though I don't think that would escape appending into a new file?

Comment: You might have changed some light path settings.

Comment: GPU vs CPU? Compatible vs Experimental mode? Color Management? Film emulation? Without a new file, it's hard to say.

Comment: All CPU (haven't got a compatible GPU.. yet..) color management is in the above screenshot, compatible mode, (file was originally created in 2.65 but had the same issue.. (same happens with 2.66b) the rest I'm not sure about and I won't have access to the .blend for a few days... :(

Comment: Here's the .blend:

   http://www.pasteall.org/blend/22200

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The flower mesh has a solidify modifier which is only enabled for rendering. The extra thickness from this modifier makes the translucent material give a different result.

In general for differences between render and viewport, check these:

- Object viewport and render visibility in the outliner
- Modifier viewport and render visibility
- Particles and hair resolution settings
- Curve, surface and metaball tessellation settings
- Render layer settings
- Color management settings
- Compositing nodes and sequencer strips

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I missed that.. I was searching for almost a day :P

Comment: This is a good reference post.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you have extra lights that are hidden in the viewport, so they're not being rendered in the viewport. However they will still render with F12, unless they are disabled at render time.

Check in the Outliner to see if you have objects that are hidden in the viewport.

[image]

Comment: I thought of that, and checked them all thoroughly..
unless I missed one, it's not that. (also check to see if it was the other way around, hidden in render, but no..)