# Discrepancy in Rendering from original model

Tags: modeling, rendering

When I have modeled and animated my project my 3d view looks like this:
[image]
While my rendering looks like this:
[image]
As you can tell the crown is distorted the pearls are being lifted off the crown and the points on the crown are no longer pointy. Why is this happening/how do I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2728/599 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/985/599

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess (can't tell for definite without a blend file) that you have a Subsurf Modifier set to be *off* in the 3D view but *on* for rendering.

Go to the modifiers panel by clicking the blue spanner/wrench and then see if you have any modifiers.

If the modifier is set to be off in the 3D view then the 'eye' icon will be disabled. Disable the 'Show in render' button (camera icon) to disable the modifier or press the 'x' button to remove it.

[image]