# Texture doesnt render correctly when rendering final image

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv

I have some strange problem in my recent Blender project.

I modelled a room with some stuff in it and I added some simple wooden texture to the floor. When I am in the 3D view and change it to "rendered" everything renders correctly. When I hit Render through the menu, I have some weird effect on the floor, somehow its totally messed up.

[image]

[image: This is what it looks like when I cahnge to rendered view in 3D view]

Does anyone know why this happens? And do you may have some advices for me , to get a noise free interior scene with blender without sampling everything thousands of times?!

Thanks in advance! -Marten

Comment: Please upload your blend file otherwise it will be difficult for people to help you.

Comment: Are there any modifiers? Are there any hidden objects?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cycles viewport render different than f12 render?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/985/599)  Related: [What are the technical differences between F12 render and viewport preview?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2728/what-are-the-technical-differences-between-f12-render-and-viewport-preview)

Answer (score 1):

Oh okay I figured it out. I had a hidden object at the same position as my floor. Woupsi..