# Weird reflections

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I made a lightsaber, and it's looking pretty good, but I have a few problems.  When I render it out, it looks like this:[image: Rendered]

However, in the viewport rendered shading, it looks like this:
[image]

How come the exact same scene can have different reflections?  I would like the rendered image to look like it does in the viewport.  How can I do this?

Comment: The viewport render uses the viewport settings for modifiers, and visibility setting for the viewport. Perhaps your Display and Render settings for a modifier, or the visibility of something in the environment, are different?

Comment: It looks to me like you have a subsurf or maybe a bevel modifier which is being not being applied in one or the other. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/985/599 for a list of possible causes.