# Render looks different to screen view

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

Any quick thoughts why the render through camera viewport (right) looks completely different to the on-screen render (left)?

[image: rendered image]

Comment: Brecht (original creator of Cycles) lists a couple of reasons here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1189/47

Answer (score 1):

Could be:

- you have changed the "exposure" in the "Film" panel the Render Tab
  and you have not re-rendered yet (i don't think is the case anyway)
- there is a lamp, or a plane, or something that is hidden in the viewport but is still marked as
  "rendered" as seen in the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: Hmm I've worked out that it's something to do with a series of lights that I imported from a x3d file. When I turn them off both scenes go dark. But why the camera is affected more must be to do with its settings... Eg. exposure or focal length? Are there any other camera settings that might affect it?

Comment: I don't think that camera settings are involved, none of them can led to this overexposure, unless thera are someme "Custom Proprety" (that my be enherited from the x3d file...but I don't think so...more probable something to do with lighting..or the compositor). If you could upload your .blend filem, or a part of it, I'm quite sure we'll be able to give you a proper answer. Could you?