# materials different between render and viewport cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials, node-editor, 3d-view

Right now I have a scene set up with two emmission shaders on two planes. In the viewport render I get this image[image]

But whenever I render it, I get this

[image]

The viewport render is as desired but the final render doesn't turn out as wanted.

here is my simple node setup for the mountains
[image]

and the backyard
[image]

If you have any tips I am greatful for them!

Comment: Can you show the modifier stack for each object? There seems to be something changing the material on the second plane.

Comment: neither of them have modifers and I have restarted the blend file as well as importing both objects into a new scene

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/985/599

Comment: Thanks my bad, Sorry for reposting. couldn't find that article.